# Where should I put the XML file in iPhone Simulator's filesystem. XCode 4.2

Tags: ios, filesystems, ios-simulator

A little embarrassing question, but I can find an answer which works in my case... I need to put some xml file (settings.xml) in order to read some data from it during application runtime.

According to some answers here and not only here, I have putted it here:
**~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/[AppUUID]/Documents**

and I'm trying to use it as follows:

```
// Loading data from external XML File
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    URLForResource: @"settings" withExtension:@"xml"];
    NSError *err;
    if ([url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err] == NO){
        NSLog(@"FILE NOT FOUND");
    }
```

Result: "FILE NOT FOUND".

I've tried to do put the file under any possible directory in 
**~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/[AppUUID]/**   and efect is still the same.

I'm using XCode 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting the file into the `.../Documents` folder then you need to use the following code to access it (you are looking for it in the App Bundle, which is a different location altogether):

```
NSString *docFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [docFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.xml"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename])
{
    // Read file
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"settings.xml file not found!");
}
```